# Beginner PHP - three or's in an if?

Tags: php, variables

It feels like an easy question. I have this:

```
{if $main neq "catalog" or $current_category.category neq ""}
        {include file="customer/bread_crumbs.tpl"}
      {/if}
```

What I also want to make so that if $main does not equal "catalog
" **or "XXX"** it won't include the breadcrumbs.

That is to say I want something like this:

```
   {if $main neq "catalog" or $main neq "XXX" or $current_category.category neq ""}
            {include file="customer/bread_crumbs.tpl"}         
          {/if}
```

Obviously this doesn't work though and I don't know PHP terms enough to figure out what question to ask.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please beware of the formatting

Comment: Thanks for the help changed to:  {if $main neq "catalog" and $main neq 'buy_together_added' or $current_category.category neq ""} and it is now working!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language this is (it looks like some template language and isn't PHP), but this is a basic boolean logic problem:

As one example, if `$main` is "catalog", then it must not be "XXX".

In this way, your condition is *always true*, because it is works out to either `false or true` or `true or false` or `true or true`, depending on the value of `$main`.

You need to use the `and` operator instead of `or`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using a template engine right ?

I've never used this kind of things in PHP but maybe what you want is if `$main` is not equal to "catalog" **and** $main is not equal to "XXX"... then include the file.

Comment: Hi @AndyK im sorry ill try to improve it next time it's the first day i really use stackoverflow. Ill be happy if you could give me some advice.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I am correct but maybe you want to do this:

```
if ($main != "catalog" || $main != "XXX" || $current_category.category != ""){

}
```

But I also dont know if you are using some template engine or something like that, so I suppose that 'neq' is 'not equal to'